# while com condições or

Tags: python, while

tenho o seguinte código:
`while (operacoes is not '+') or (operacoes is not '-') or (operacoes is not '*') or (operacoes is not '/'):
    operacoes = str(input('Escolha uma das operações matemáticas a seguir: ( +, -, * ou / ): '))`

Se eu não fornecer alguma das quatro operações matemáticas pedidas, ele vai continuar me pedindo uma operação, porém, quando eu forneço alguma das operações, ele não sai do looping.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: @Maniero, obrigado pelo feedback. Como faço para sinalizar minha pergunta como respondida?

Comment: Não precisa fazer nada.